# Installing package R4CouchDB version 0.5.1 on R 3.1

Tags: r, couchdb, nodes, cloudant, install.packages

I am stuck on a project I am working on. The installation instruction says:

This node uses the package R4CouchDB version 0.5.1. At this time, this version is not available on the official cran repository, so we will download it from github and install it in R 3.1
Launch R 3.1 and copy paste the following code in the R console:

```
###Code Starts here
if (!require("downloader"))
install.packages("downloader")
require(downloader)
url <- "https://github.com/wactbprot/R4CouchDB/archive/master.zip"
zipfile <- paste(getwd(), "/R4CouchDB.zip", sep="")
download(url=url, destfile=zipfile)
unzip(zipfile=zipfile, exdir=getwd())
targzfile <- paste(getwd(), "/R4CouchDB-master/R4CouchDB_0.5.1.tar.gz",sep="")
install.packages(targzfile, repos=NULL, type="source")
unlink(paste(getwd(), "/R4CouchDB-master"), recursive=TRUE)
file.remove(zipfile)
###Code Ends here
```

However, when I run this on my windows system, it does not install the package. It returns an invalid package warning and no packages specified error

Comment: There is no `R4CouchDB_0.5.1.tar.gz` in the zip archive.

Comment: @Pascal, what could be the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put in `R` console:

```
install.packages("R4CouchDB")
library("R4CouchDB")
```